# Bitbucket automatic merge pull request from release branch

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, pull-request

I have question. How do you deal with "Automatic merge" option from bitbucket.

[image: automatic merge]

My problem:

[image: problem]

So bug detection on release/1.1 have pom version of release branch. If I create pull request to relase/1.1 branch after review etc, bug should be merged to relase branch and master to but here it will be conflict.

[image: failure]

Do you have any tip to resolve this ? Becouse this option is useless when person have to again resolve conflict in pom version.

Comment: you have conflicts only if the pom file has changed. if it did so, you do have to resolve conflicts. How would you expect it to be ? who if not you would know what to do with the conflict ? git can't decide it for you. If conflicts are always the say, you probably could write a script that automatically resolves problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your automated merge would always (or oftentimes) result in a conflict, then I agree with you that the value is greatly lessened. However, I wouldn't go as far as saying it's "useless". When a merge conflict occurs BitBucket creates a Pull Request for you, which if nothing else serves as a reminder that you need to complete the merge yourself.

**Side Note:** the automatic merge feature is intended to automate merging *downstream* to other "lower" release branches and/or finally landing on a branch like `develop` if one exists. Typically, `master` would be considered *upstream* to a `release` branch. This doesn't change the question, or the answer, and you can still use it the way you described if you wish. Just make sure you actually do want to automate merging into `master` for every completed PR into `release`.